# Disable the scrolling to the top of a page before opening a sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I open a sidebar, how do I disable the scrolling to the top of the page before opening?

I want to be able to have the page stay at the same position of the window when opening the sidebar!

Comment: use `position: fixed` so the sidebar will be fixed and doesn't get out the screen of the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `position: fixed` and `top: 0` `left: 0` then it will stay in the same position on the page.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mu995/